# Append/Substitute string in Makefile from another makefile

Tags: c++, linux, makefile

I wanted to string substitute this one string in one of the .mak file my main Makefile includes, like so:

/boo.mak

```
[...]

LOADLIBES += -lGoo
LOADLIBES += -lBaa -lCov -lDtt  // -lDtt to be replaced

[...]
```

/Makefile

```
[...]

include $(DIR)/boo.mak

[...]
```

The `-lDtt`is to be replaced by something like `-Wl, --do-something -lDtt -Wl --undo-something`

How would you recommend to do this?
I've tried this:

/test

```
[...]
replace:= -Wl, --do-something -lDtt -Wl --undo-something
dtt:= -lDtt
boo:= $(DIR)/boo.mak

newboo:= $(subst $(dtt),$(replace),$(boo))

include $(newboo)
[...]
```

But nothing changed, the -lDtt still exist and does not replace with the text I wanted after I run.

Edit: I'm using gcc and linux.

Answer (score 1):

The third parameter to `$(subst` is the actual string to replace. It is not the name of the file where the string is found, as you seem to believe.

Example:

```
$ cat Makefile
replace:= -Wl, --do-something -lDtt -Wl --undo-something
dtt:= -lDtt
boo:= This string contains -lDtt which will be replaced

newboo:= $(subst $(dtt),$(replace),$(boo))

testme:
    echo $(newboo)
$ make testme
echo This string contains -Wl, --do-something -lDtt -Wl --undo-something which will be replaced
This string contains -Wl, --do-something -lDtt -Wl --undo-something which will be replaced
```

So, in your case, you will need to use the `$(subst` on the `LOADLIBES` variable, to replace its contents.

Comment: So that would mean my `boo:=` will be equal to the `LOADLIBES` ? Is that correct ? Thus `boo:= $(LOADLIBES)` ?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, thanks to the above answer. I manage to get an insight of what was wrong and next steps I should take to make things work. Here is my current Makefile:

```
[...]

include $(DIR)/boo.mak

replace:= -Wl, --do-something -lDtt -Wl --undo-something
dtt:= -lDtt
boo:= $(subst $(dtt),$(replace),$(LOADLIBES))

LOADLIBES = $(boo) //replace old LOADLIBES variable with new modified lib

[...]
```

I'm open to any suggestion to make this better but it is working fine for now.